# Turning masked results into different random numbers

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, mask

I want to do something like this.

```
import numpy

# Create a 10x10 array of random numbers.
example_array = numpy.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=(10, 10))

# Locate values that equal 5 and turn them into a new random number.
example_array[example_array == 5] = numpy.random.random_integers(0, 10)
```

The problem is with the last line. It applies a single random number to all masked values instead of a new random number per value. For example, if the number 2 is chosen then all values that == 5 become 2. I want an entirely new value for each of them, not for all of them to have the same random value. I hope that makes sense! Please advise.

Apologies for any confusion. I have not got numpy terminology down pat yet.

Here is another example that might help.

```
# Before replacing 5's with a random number.
array=[4, 5, 5,
       5, 2, 3,
       5, 4, 5]

# After replacing 5's with a random number.
array=[4, 1, 4,
       7, 2, 3,
       2, 4, 8]
```

It seems like something that should be easy to do but I cannot figure out how to do it efficiently. I want to do it using a mask for speed purposes. My currently working (and super slow!) method is to loop over the array and roll the dice for any values that need randomization.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.random.choice` with the number of elements to be masked -

```
import numpy as np

mask = example_array == 5
select_nums = np.r_[:5,6:10] # array from which elements are to be picked up
                             # we need to skip number 5, so we are using np.r_
                             # to concatenate range arrays
example_array[mask] = np.random.choice(select_nums, mask.sum())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped increase the map generation speed of my game by 182%! I upvoted but am new so unfortunately it's hidden for the time being.